# Process credit card in 5 months via paypal

Tags: drupal, paypal, ubercart

My client has a drupal + ubercart site. now he wants to setup a product for preorder. Meaning, take the credit card info now, but charge only after 5 months. Is there any way this can be achieved?

originally I thought about using authorization (the site is using paypal as gateway). But, the authorizations lasts only 29 days.

I understand that storing all the credit card info is a big no-no. but maybe there is some solution to this?

Comment: maybe you can let them buy voucher on Paypal, after 5 month, you just spend it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would need PayPal [Preapproved Payments](https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/recurring-payments-reference-transactions-and-preapproved-payments), available via the PayPal [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments) API.
Buyers would authorize (preapprove) you to charge them at a later date for up to a certain amount. When that time comes, you would simply call the PayPal Adaptive `Pay` API and charge them.

For an example checkout flow, see the [Adaptive Payments Developer Guide (page 25)](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf)
See also page 171 onwards for an integration example with the `Preapproval` API.

Comment: The only downside to this, is that the funds aren't guaranteed to be available in five months time. But you won't get around this; you can't realistically hold funds for five months time.